# Cannot Copy Firebase Database Node Data to Another Node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am simply trying to copy information I have saved in one Firebase location to another:

```
        mFollowingCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b){
                mBaseRef.child(USERS_LABEL).child(mUserID).child(FOLLOWING_LABEL).child(USERS_LABEL).child(mPollCreatorID).child(DISPLAY_NAME_LABEL).setValue(mPollCreatorDisplayName);
                mBaseRef.child(POLL_LABEL).child(pollID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        mBaseRef.child(USERS_LABEL).child(mUserID).child(FOLLOWING_LABEL).child(POLL_LABEL).child(pollID).setValue(dataSnapshot);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

            } else {
                mBaseRef.child(USERS_LABEL).child(mUserID).child(FOLLOWING_LABEL).child(USERS_LABEL).child(mPollCreatorID).child(DISPLAY_NAME_LABEL).removeValue();
            }
        }
    });
```

When I have this code, the app is simply crashing. There is no logging error and I am unable to pinpoint exactly what I am doing incorrectly. Essentially, I would like to know best practice for copying Firebase data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `onDataChange()` you should be storing the *value* of the [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot), not the `Datasnapshot` object itself.

Change:

```
setValue(dataSnapshot);
```

to

```
setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

Also, your code to show a `Toast` is wrong:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`databaseError.getCode()` returns an `int`, which means you are calling the form of [makeText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) that expects a string resource ID.  Change to:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Perfect, it now works correctly appreciate the help. Also, I have numerous .addSingleEventListeners() in my .onCreateView() method, all linked to different nodes within my Firebase database. Is it alright to have multiple listeners or is it best practice to have 1 listener at the base node and work from there?

Comment: I don't see a problem with having a listener for each node you want to copy.